# Função que retorna quantidade de nós de uma arvore que possuem os dois campos esq e dir diferentes de null

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, árvore-binária

Tenho uma árvore binária de busca na qual criei uma função que deve retornar a quantidade de nós que possuem os dois filhos (campos dir e esq diferentes de NULL), mas minha função não dá o valor esperado.

A ordem de inserção é a seguinte: 3,5,2,4,7,0,2,8,7,9
Ao meu ver, deveria retornar 4, mas só está retornando o valor 3.

```
int getLeafCount(ArvBinaria  *a){
if(a == NULL)       
return 0;
else if (a->sae != NULL && a->sad!=NULL)      
return 1 + getLeafCount(a->sae)+ getLeafCount(a->sad);   
}
```

Comment: Como se comporta a arvore em relação a repetições ? Tanto o `2` como o `7` tem repetições

Comment: Depende da implementação, não dá para saber se o problema está aí ou em outra parte, ou se, baseando no seu algoritmo, sua interpretação é que está errada.

Comment: Olhei aqui e realmente a repetição influencia, sem ela a implementação dá certa. Pro caso que estou trabalhando já é o suficiente, mas vou tentar deixar de uma forma que aceite a repetição, vlw